# How to define a 2D list

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

While defining a 2D dynamic array why can't I define it like this:

```
List<List<Integer>> t=new List<List<Integer>();
```

On doing so, I got an error saying:

```
Cannot instantiate the type List<List<Integer>>
```

I came to know that this is the best practice for it-

```
List<List<Integer>> t=new Arraylist<List<Integer>>();
```

why is it so.can someone help me understand this.

Comment: `List<List<WhatEverYourGenericTypeIs>>`

Comment: `ArrayList` is just the most used `List` because it implements the `List` as an basic array (hence the name `ArrayList`). In most cases that is what you're looking for a index sorted list with a dynamic length. There are also `LinkedList` and other lists just look it up if you want to know there difference. You should know the basics of data containers such as arrays, lists, maps and sets.

Comment: Java uses a strict type system. You can only assign values to variables which have the same type or an subtype. Furthermore, there are interfaces in Java. Interfaces as well as abstract classes cannot be instantiated since they are abstract structures. To instantiate such an interface or abstract class, you have to define a class which uses the interface or inherit the properties of the abstract class. From this class you can create instances. For example, the ArrayList is a class which implements the List interface. Therefore, you can create instances of it.

Comment: List is an interface, it is not a class on it's own. So you have to have an implementation. Eg, ArrayList is a class that implements the List interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[List is an interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) an as such can not use new to create a new instance of it, you need classes  that implement it instead eg ArrayList

```
List<List<Integer>> t=new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

or since java 7
List<List<Integer>> t = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: then how is this possible-List<Integer> t= new List<Integer>

Answer (score 0):

Because in Java, List is an Interface you can't initialize it.
You can do it like that;

```
List<t> list = new ArrayList<t>();
```

Just initialize any types that implement the List Interface

Comment: A good Java IDE should display the possible classes that implement the List interface.